# Partial Methods in C# and parameters

Tags: c#, ref, out, partial-methods

Ref and out can change the behavior of function parameters. Sometimes we want the actual value of a variable to be copied as the parameter. Other times we want a reference. These modifiers affect definite assignment analysis.

My question is: can partial methods in C# have ref, out, optional input parameters?

Comment: have you tried it yet? :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-methods

Comment: From the above linked docs: *Partial methods can have ref but not out parameters.*

Answer (score 1):

By experimentation with the code in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-method) it seems like you can find that it is possible to use `ref`, `params`, and default argument values, but not `out`

```
partial class A
{
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(string s);
    partial void useRef(ref string s);
    partial void useOpt(string s1, string s2 = null);
    partial void useArgs(params string [] s);
}

// This part can be in a separate file.
partial class A
{
    // Comment out this method and the program
    // will still compile.
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(String s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

Also, as explained by [the docs linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-methods) by @user6144226 and pointed out by @marc_s:

> Partial methods can have ref but not out parameters.

Comment: The tooltip for downvotes says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Well, there you have it.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why Partial methods does not supports OUT parameters ?